# Optimization Opportunities: UISwitch mask - custom offTintColor

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uiswitch

While debugging the View Hierarchy, I came across this optimization warning about a `UISwitch` control with a mask view. Though I have no clear picture what would be the benefits of addressing this warning (insights please), I tried to fix it with no success.

> Optimization Opportunities: The layer is using a simple layer with background color set as a mask. Instead, use a container layer of the same `frame` and `cornerRadius` as the mask, but with `masksToBounds` set to YES.

```
        let maskedSwitch: UISwitch = UISwitch()
        maskedSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        maskedSwitch.tintColor = .black
        maskedSwitch.onTintColor = .green
        maskedSwitch.backgroundColor = .black
        
        let maskView = UIView(frame: maskedSwitch.frame)
        maskView.backgroundColor = .black
        maskView.layer.cornerRadius = maskedSwitch.frame.height / 2
        maskView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        maskView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        maskedSwitch.mask = maskView
        let scale: CGFloat = 2.5 / 3
        maskedSwitch.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
```

As suggested, I tried removing the maskView and directly applying the cornerRadius and offTintColor on switch. But it ended up messing the scale transformation, and it is kind of important to retain the UI.

How can I further optimise the code and make sure all these conditions addressed: 1. set offTintColor to black, 2. scale the switch and 3. Avoid the optimization opportunity warning?

Note: Please do share if there is an Apple doc to study more on the topic `Optimization Opportunities`. Thanks!